# How to call a route which is present in different MFE in Angular 12

Tags: angular, angular-material, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router, router-outlet

I am having 2 MFEs A & B which have been created in angular 12 and running at different ports. They are connected through a shell app. I need to create a page which shows some data from MFE A and some data from MFE B. In short the requirements are,

1. 1 component from MFE B needs to be embedded into 1 component of MFE A,
2. I need to pass some from MFE A to B, on the basis of which B will display the data. The route at MFE B is /file/:id

How can I achieve this.

I have already done the configurations at MFE B and shell. I tested this and through shell I can hit the route of MFE B.